# Locale based information on International site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

We're building an education platform. The site it's going to be published in different countries, having each country its own subfolder. For example,

France: http://myedusite.com/fr/

Spain: http://myedusite.com/es/

- The site has `courses` belonging to `providers`
- `courses` have different `themes` (Arts, Business, Science) and these themes have sub-themes (I'm planning to use [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to have a tree structure model)

**Courses**

`providers` can create courses if they have an account. The courses created will be published only in the domain they were created. 
As an example, if I'm a course's provider and I create an account in http://myedusite.com/fr/, then the courses I create should only be published in http://myedusite.com/fr/.

For this purpose, I thought of defining a `Country` model with the field `iso_3166`. This field would be populated with the country codes defined in [ISO 3166](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes).

Then, the `courses` would have a `target_country` (class: `Country`), enabling the possibility of choosing where the course is published (if the course's `target_country` is France it should only be visible in http://myedusite.com/fr/).

**Themes**

For `themes` happens something similar, where for each country where the site exists there can be different themes. When a user arrives to http://myedusite.com/xx/, only `themes` existing in country "xx" will be shown. That implies that each `theme` should belong to a `country`.

On the other hand, each course would have one `theme`.

For dealing with country related information (for example loading cities for a country) I thought of using the [country gem](https://github.com/hexorx/countries).

From the business perspective, we have chosen a bottom-top approach, meaning that only the necessary things are built now, adding features as it's needed.

I see this as a reasonable strategy to make the site international. What I'm afraid of is of choosing wrong and having trouble on the future as new features arrive. I would like to have as much flexibility as possible.

It's the first time I design an international project. Is the approach I've thought of something usual in this kind of sites? Anything I should pay attention to that I didn't mention?

Comment: Seems ok. However you might want to anticipate there being more than one `target_country` and use a many-to-many relation.

Answer (score 0):

I use navigator.language to get the locale and redirect from JS to whatever URL I want, or add it as a query string. In your case since you only want the language you should split it first, then redirect. In my case I use the full locale code because en is different from AU, US, CA, GB and so on, you'd probably want to consider doing the same especially if you will be displaying prices, dates and so on.

I think there is a way to get this with Rails too, see the Accept-language, accept charset headers.

Once you pass the language/locale to your controller you can then filter data as required.

This also leaves room for some nice SEO tricks if you set up a custom 404 page, engines will go for this.